# Connecting SOAP UI groovy to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, groovy, soapui

I found this question: [soapUI access MS SQL DB from groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791680/soapui-access-ms-sql-db-from-groovy-script) but it refers to using the MS SQL driver.

So I'm following the instructions here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL I wrote the following groovy script to connect to my local database:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://thehl7:1433/agilejury-thehl_MC', 'user', 'password', 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' )
sql.eachRow( 'select * from pool_person' ) { println "$it.pool_id -- ${it.person_id} --" }
```

I was getting class not found, but I placed the jar file in my ext directory and got past that one. Now I'm getting java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://thehl7:1433/agilejury-thehl_MC.

Comment: When you say _"not working"_, what do you mean?  Does it throw an exception? Does it just not print anything?

Comment: Sorry, @tim_yates, that was clumsy of me. I edited the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer was here even though I'm getting an entirely different message. [SoapUI + sqlite-jdbc = ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774788/soapui-sqlite-jdbc-classnotfoundexception)

I registered my jdbc driver and the error disappeared.